# how to access HDFS extended attributes in java code

Tags: hdfs, bigdata

How can I access extended attributes of a HDFS file or directory in my java code? Any pointers will help.

Thanks and Regards,

Abhay Dandekar

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileSystem` class to access and modify them:

There is a method called getXAttr, here is the piece of the documentation taken from the API

> `public byte[] getXAttr(Path path, String name) throws IOException`
>
> Get an xattr name and value for a file or directory. The name must be
>   prefixed with the namespace followed by ".". For example, "user.attr".
>
> Refer to the HDFS extended attributes user documentation for details.
>
> Parameters:
>       `path` - Path to get extended attribute
>       `name` - xattr name.
>   Returns:
>       `byte[]` xattr value.

You can check the whole API [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getXAttr(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Thats a bit strange. I know about this getXAttr API in FileSystem. Somehow, its not visible in my IDE on  dot alt + space. Also, I checked with the FS implementation in hadoop codebase, and its coded to throw UnsupportedOperationException.  Is there any blog which can guide us through some running example? - Thanks again.

Comment: Are you using the Filesystem from org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem ?? I'm using it from hadoop-common version 2.6.0-cdh-5.11.1

Comment: Yeah .. Using the same hadoop filesystem object.